# How to avoid a text image captcha in web scraping using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, captcha

Hello: I am performing web **scraping** using Selenium but I encounter a text image captcha which appears randomly after a few records are **scraped**. Perhaps someone can give a hint on how to avoid it in the first place, which I presume is much easier than trying to bypass it through image/text recognition. If I manually **scrape** the website, the captcha also appears from time to time. Many thanks, Alejandro

--

```
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager    
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

start_time = time.time()

list_provinces = ["A CORUÑA", "ALAVA", "ALBACETE", "ALCALÁ DE HENARES", "ALCOY", "ALICANTE", "ALMERÍA", "ALZIRA", "ANTEQUERA", "AVILA", "BADAJOZ", "BALEARES", "BARCELONA", "BIZKAIA", "BURGOS", "CÁCERES", "CÁDIZ", "CANTABRIA", "CARTAGENA", "CASTELLÓN", "CEUTA", "CIUDAD REAL", "CÓRDOBA", "CUENCA", "ELCHE", "ESTELLA", "FERROL", "FIGUERES", "GIJÓN", "GIPUZKOA", "GIRONA", "GRANADA", "GRANOLLERS", "GUADALAJARA", "HUELVA", "HUESCA", "JAÉN", "JEREZ DE LA FRONTERA", "LANZAROTE", "LA RIOJA", "LAS PALMAS", "LEÓN", "LLEIDA", "LORCA", "LUCENA", "LUGO", "MADRID", "MÁLAGA", "MANRESA", "MATARÓ", "MELILLA", "MURCIA", "ORIHUELA", "OURENSE", "OVIEDO", "PALENCIA", "PAMPLONA", "PONTEVEDRA", "REUS", "SABADELL", "SALAMANCA", "SANTA CRUZ DE LA PALMA", "SANTA CRUZ DE TENERIFE", "SANT FELIU", "SANTIAGO", "SEGOVIA", "SEVILLA", "SORIA", "SUECA", "TAFALLA", "TALAVERA DE LA REINA", "TARRAGONA", "TARRASSA", "TERUEL", "TOLEDO", "TORTOSA", "TUDELA", "VALENCIA", "VALLADOLID", "VIC", "VIGO", "ZAMORA", "ZARAGOZA"]
range_provinces = [325, 86, 177, 154, 52, 451, 296, 78, 20, 54, 166, 414, 2430, 483, 107, 96, 265, 216, 109, 170, 61, 131, 235, 48, 112, 8, 63, 26, 138, 204, 191, 355, 75, 82, 160, 80, 201, 63, 39, 97, 461, 178, 121, 48, 1122, 88, 7531, 612, 46, 64, 31, 453, 104, 154, 424, 43, 160, 145, 49, 113, 150, 219, 393, 98, 139, 45, 788, 28, 80, 5, 32, 138, 79, 25, 103, 42, 21, 1175, 159, 42, 236, 61, 346]

url = "https://www.abogacia.es/servicios-abogacia/censo-de-letrados/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get(url)

new_lawyer = []

count = -1

#Accept cookies

try:
        
    cookiesButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cookie_action_close_header"]')
    cookiesButton.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    
except:
        
    print('No cookies')
        
for province in list_provinces:
    
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    
    print(province)
    
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,5)*0.1)
    
    try:
    
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        
        # locate dropdown list and select province from list
    
        driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//iframe[contains(@src,'homeColegiados')]"))
        
        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//select[@class='iceSelOneMnu']"))

        select.select_by_visible_text(province)
        
        # locate button to go to province
        
        button = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="j_id23:idBuscar"]')))
        
        # click button to go to province
        
        button.click()
    
        time.sleep(1)
        
        # find all lawyers info in the current page

        Web_Element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//table[@class='iceDatTbl tablaElementos']/tbody/tr")

        for element in Web_Element:
            
            # append lawyers info into list
            
            info = element.get_attribute('innerText')
            new_lawyer.append(info)
    
        # click button to go to next lawyer page
    
        for i in range(1,range_provinces[count]+1,1):
        
            try:
                
                wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            
                # find button to go to next lawyer page
                
                new_button = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="j_id23:j_id79"]')))
                
                # click button to go to next lawyer page
                
                new_button.click()
    
                time.sleep(1)
    
                # find all lawyers info in the current page
                
                Web_Element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//table[@class='iceDatTbl tablaElementos']/tbody/tr")

                for element in Web_Element:
                    
                    # append lawyers info into list
                    
                    new_info = element.get_attribute('innerText')
                    new_lawyer.append(new_info)
        
            except:
                
                # exit for loop if there's no more lawyers in that province
                
                print("no more lawyers in:", province)
                
                break
    
    except:
        
        print("province end", province)
        continue
    
    count = count +1
    
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,5)*0.1)
    
driver.quit()

end_time = time.time()

print((end_time - start_time) / 60)
```

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap. 'To scrap' means to throw away like rubbish :-(

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @barny although not very useful for my question

Comment: It sounds like you might be asking about avoiding bot detection (reCaptchav3?), there's a few good answers for selenium + python if you search for that.